# How to display HTML content in github README.md?

Tags: github, markdown

I am new to github, in `README.md` want to display a HTML content using an Iframe or something is this possible ?

What I have tried is I just create HTML tags other then anchor, that is not working.

Comment: Other suggestions in the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402823/embed-openstreetmap-iframe-in-github-markdown

Answer (score 61):

Github's markdown interpreter *can* include HTML. However, there is only so much you can do in HTML. I would suggest checking out [this article](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) which provides more information on what tags can be used. Personally, I have never used much more than line-breaks, horizontal rules, etc... Unfortunately, I don't see Iframes mentioned in the article.

Comment: They aggressively remove html that could be harmful to users, such as scripts. An iframe would fall under that category because you could potentially serve people anything, even malware right there on github.

Answer (score 59):

As answered by [mjgpy3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951401/103577), you *can* include html - no `<html>` tags needed, but it'll be sanitized before display and the only tags allowed are in [this whitelist](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html_pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb).

The list currently includes:

`h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 br b i strong em a pre code img tt div ins del sup sub p ol ul table thead tbody tfoot blockquote dl dt dd kbd q samp var hr ruby rt rp li tr td th s strike summary details caption figure figcaption abbr bdo cite dfn mark small span time wbr`

but no `iframe`.

Comment: lazysoundsystem's posted list Changed, See line # 46,47,48 for ALLOWED HTML TAGs: [GitHub-HTML-pipeline-sanitization_filter.rb](https://github.com/github/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization%5Ffilter%2Erb), I verified+found the link is correct, at this moment. Such TAGs Not-Allowed : script, style, iframe, span,… But div, table,…partially allowed. GitHub also removes/filters many Attributes used inside TAGs. As GitHub can apply Filter on TAGs & Attrib(s), They should allow <style>,<script>,…with Filtering-ON, to allow at-least some safe CSS+JS Properties/Commands.

Answer (score 20):

You can use svg to work around, example code (./path/example.svg):

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<foreignObject width="100" height="100">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Other embed HTML element/text into SVG -->
    </div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

and then use image insert way to embed the svg file in any other markdown file, like this:

```
![](./path/example.svg)
```

Comment: what an answer body

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity! I can now create tables in github that don't look totally bonkers!