# Markdown - icon on the left of a title

Tags: html, github, markdown

so what I want is on a given H1 main title to have an icon on the left-hand side. Unfortunately, so far I did not find any way to achieve this. One potential variant is to write bare bone HTML for both, however, I don't get the benefit of the markdown inside the title. 
Does anyway know any better way to do this?

First to show what I actually want is this (this was done with picture editor for demonstration):
[image]

I have tried this:

```
![image-title-here](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png)
# Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines
```

[image]

## Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines

This does not work at all

```
![](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png){:style="float: right;margin-right: 7px;margin-top: 7px;"}
# Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines
```

[image]{:style="float: right;margin-right: 7px;margin-top: 7px;"}

## Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines

Using html like so, does not recognize the markdown:

```html
<p align="center">
    ![]((https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png)
</p>
```

Using direct html also:

```html
<div style="float: left;"><img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" width="128" height="128"/></div> 
# Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines
```

Here if the title is not on a new line it is not recognized as markdown.

**EDIT** The suggested answer looks correct on stackoverflow, but on my github it looks like this:
[image]

The question is can we make the title to be aligned with the top of the image?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  This description is not sufficiently clear as it stands.

Comment: I've edited to try to describe what I want. If you need more details let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, GitHub does not support the full set of HTML elements in a README.md file.  [Here is a write-up](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) about what *is* supported.  I also found out a bit more in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951321/how-to-display-html-content-in-github-readme-md) from 4 years ago.

One of the resources mentioned in that question is [this whitelist](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L45-L48).

If it worked, what you would need is similar to what is below, which I have kept for your reference. The description is aimed at your problem description.  Unfortunately, it looks like GitHub overrides the `style` attribute, replacing it with `width: 100%` and forcing the text to wrap below the image.

What should work (but doesn't): The style is attached to the image itself.  Attaching it to the `div` affects the entire div.  Note: the `<h1>` consists of both the image and the text.

```
    
<h1> <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png"
  width="128"
  height="128"
  style="float:left;">
    # Quite a long title, potentially going over several lines and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on
```

Comment: Ah, that is yes! Unfortunately, on my github the title starts at the bottom of the image, check the updated question.

Comment: What do you mean by "on my github"?  I suspect that there may be some CSS attached to the H1 or IMAGE, but I can't explore that from what you have described. You would need to use the Computed Styles tab in the Browser Inspector to find out more.  [This article](http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector) is an introduction.

Comment: I mean when I apply it on a github repository. Essentially I want this to be displayed this way when github renders my README. I will read the arcticle thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with web pages attached to github repos, but I'm interested in learning more.  Can you point me to a page that describes them.  Bonus points if it talks about HTML in those pages.

Comment: So this is the repo I'm testing: https://github.com/botev/test. As to your question I think this is the correct place: https://github.com/github/markup

Comment: I did not know one could put HTML in a README.MD.  Interesting.  Also, I see the problem and updated the answer.  You do not want to put any `<p>` elements at the beginning and also need to include the `<img>` element and the text within the same `<h1>` element.

Comment: I did not know my self until recently. I've updated according to your suggestion, you can check the test repo again, however still the title only first line is aligned at the image

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce this in my own account, identify the problem--Github is sanitizing the HTML you provide it and find some references to the situation.  I have updated my answer accordingly. I know I was not able to help solve your problem, but I would appreciate your marking this answer as definitive so it may help others.

Answer (score 12):

I used image html tag and a space before the header for my GitHub project repository README.md file. to set my image on the left and title on the right. Here is the code for it.

```
<img align="left" width="80" height="80" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akarsh/akarsh-seggemu-resume/master/akarsh%20seggemu%20resume/Assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60%403x.png" alt="Resume application project app icon">

# Resume application project
```

This is how it looks,
[image: This images shows the preview of the above code]

[You can see the project readme by clicking on this link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/akarsh/akarsh-seggemu-resume)