# Can you embed a spotify song to a github README file?

Tags: github, markdown, embed, spotify, readme

I know this isn't really that important but I thought it would be fun if you could embed a spotify to your markdown.
I tried pasting this into the README.md-file but it didn't transform into a widget:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1UgMLFmeVyphjePcN1TNpq" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Can somebody tell me if it's possible to embed this using markdown?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to use iframes inside of your README on GitHub. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42444717) has to do with the same underlying issue you're having. In short, iframes are not on the list of allowed HTML tags. You can see which tags are allowed here: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/245#issuecomment-357613929

Answer (score 0):

You can just put this line of code in your README file:

```
[![Spotify](https://spotify-github-readme.vercel.app/api/spotify)](https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks)
```

And it will display the Spotify songs in your README file

Answer (score 0):

There is this lovely ***Spotify Now Playing Status***, which displays what are you listening to right now.

Go here: [spotify-github-profile](https://github.com/kittinan/spotify-github-profile)

Here are simple steps:

> - Click the connect with spotify button
> - Design your NowPlaying Stutus
> - Copy MarkDown code
> - Paste MarkDown code

With every refresh of your profile it fetches the Spotify track.
There is also setting of ***Show Offline***, if when selected it shows that you are currently not playing anything on Spotify, if *Show Offline* is left unmarked:
`show_offline=false` then, the widget grabs one of recently played track and displays it, but not in playing mode. 
One more thing to know is, it displays the status independently of your GitHub activity.