# Read me, gitHub

Tags: html, css, github, vertical-alignment, readme

I was designing my profile in GitHub and i meet some difficulty with HTML in "Readme.md"

```
<div display=flex; align-items=flex-start; flex-direction=row;>
  <p align="center" >  <img  src="https://www.codewars.com/users/yefimchuk/badges/large" alt="https://www.codewars.com/users/yefimchuk" />

   <p align="center"    > <img src="https://leetcode-stats-six.vercel.app/api?username=KnlnKS&theme=dark" alt="https://github.com/KnlnKS/leetcode-stats" />
   <img  src="https://github-readme-stackoverflow.vercel.app/?userID=17754802&theme=dark" alt="https://stackoverflow.com/users/17754802/yefimchuk" />
</div>

   <p  align="center"> <img src="github-contribution-grid-snake.svg" />
  </div>
```

It looks so: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDv5q.png)
but i wanna that two my block below was aligned by top, like by flex :

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: flex-start">
  <div>first block</div>
  <div>second block</div>
</div>
```

but I can't do this in the readMe.md file in GitHub. How I can do this, I try vertical-align: top, but this, still don't work

finally, it's should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS55D.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML content in github README.md?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951321/how-to-display-html-content-in-github-readme-md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub allows HTML in Markdown, but for security, functionality, and accessibility reasons, it strips out much of the formatting from all HTML produced.  Therefore, it you have anything that uses a `style` tag or certain other formatting approaches, they'll be removed.

If you want to do complex formatting, you should put that on a website, which could be GitHub Pages, and link to it from a simpler README.